# CogComp-NLP: Is it multi-threadable?

Tags: nlp

Is it possible to run the [CogComp-NLP](https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/pipeline) pipeline on lots of corpus on a multi-threaded fashion? I don't see any mentions of thread-safetiy in their readme, unfortunately. Thoughts on this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking only to the Named Entity Recognition feature, it is thread safe, I have used it in a parallel workflow engine to process millions (like 90 or so) of documents without problem. I can't speak authoritatively on the other capabilities in that system, and there are many. I would further characterize NER's multi-threading capabilities as "re-entrant", meaning you can reuse a single instance across multiple threads. The feature vectors tend to be large with these sorts of system, so save yourself some memory footprint, and share a single instance of the NER model across multiple threads.